# Class not found

Tags: php, phalcon

I made a research but the results was not related to my problem : I have a model whose associated table contains an underscore.

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query;

class TableClient extends Model {

    public function getSource()
    {
        return "table_client";
    }

    function lireParCritere($critere) {

        $sSQL = "
                SELECT c.table_code,s.salle_code,s.salle_lib,c.table_lib,c.table_nb_couvert,c.table_comment 
                FROM table_client as c INNER JOIN salle s ON s.salle_code = c.salle_code
                WHERE 1 = 1 ";

        if(isset($critere["table_code"]) && $critere["table_code"] != "") {
            $sSQL .= "AND c.table_code = '" . $critere["table_code"] . "' ";    
        }

        $query = new Query($sSQL,$this->getDI());

        $ret = $query->execute();

        return $ret;

    }

    function ajouter($tab) {
        $champs= "";
        $value = "";
        $separateur ="";

        foreach ($tab as $k => $v){
            $champs .= $separateur . $k;
            $value .= $separateur . "'" . $v . "'";
            $separateur = ",";
        }
        $champs = '('.$champs.')';
        $value = '('.$value.')';
        $sSQL = "
                INSERT INTO table_client $champs
                VALUES $value
                ";
        $query = new Query($sSQL,$this->getDI());
        $ret = $query->execute();
    }

    function modifier($tab) {

        $setColumns = "";
        $separateur = "";

        foreach ($tab as $k => $v){
            if ($k == 'table_code')
                continue;
            $setColumns .= $separateur . 'table_client.' . $k . " = '" . $v . "'";
            $separateur = ",";
        }

        $sSQL = "UPDATE table_client SET ".$setColumns." WHERE table_client.table_code = '".$tab['table_code']."'";

        $query = new Query($sSQL, $this->getDI());
        $ret = $query->execute();
    }

    function supprimer($tab) {
        $sSQL = "DELETE FROM table_client WHERE table_client.table_code = '".$tab['table_code']."'";
        $query = new Query($sSQL, $this->getDI());
        $ret = $query->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

Inside a `controller` I want to call a method of this model :

```
public function modifierAction($id){
        $this->view->action_form = '../modifierExec';
        $this->view->titre = 'Modification de table';
        $critere = array();
        $critere["table_code"] = $id;
        $this->view->data = TableClient::lireParCritere($critere); // here is the call of the model's method
        return $this->view->pick("table/table");
    }
```

At runtime I get a class not found error ! So how to fix it ?

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: Probably unrelated but you access the method statically,so either make the method static or use the instantiate operator `Table->lireParCritere`

Comment: on the page I got : `Exception: Model 'table_client' could not be loaded` , and in error log file I got `Fatal error:  Class 'table_client' not found in D:\wamp\www\resto\app\controllers\ReferentielTableController.php on line 35`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check class by [class_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) function
2. Check Phalcon autoloader config. Make sure you really put in the autoloader config class/directory/namespace/
3. You can check class availability in constroller:

   ```
   foreach (spl_autoload_functions() as $function) {
       foreach ($function as $object) {
           if (!$object instanceof \Phalcon\Loader) {
               continue;
           }

           var_dump($object->getNamespaces());
           var_dump($object->getCheckedPath());
           var_dump($object->getDirs());
           var_dump($object->getClasses());
           var_dump($object->getFoundPath());
       }
   }

   die;
   ```

**Edit**

4. \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query uses [PHQL](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html), not SQL. In `function lireParCritere($critere)` use `FROM \Fully\Qualified\Class\Name` instead  `FROM table_client`
5. For tests use `$client = new TableClient; $client->lireParCritere($critere);` instead `TableClient::lireParCritere($critere);`

Comment: So when we write `SELECT some_columns FROM ` then the name after the `FROM` keyword is a class model name ?

Comment: @pheromix For PHQL yes